# Disable sound in push notification phonegap - android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, urbanairship.com

Trying to disable sound of Push Notifications in my phonegap(2.2.0) app using

```
setSoundEnabled(Boolean enabled, callback)
```

Note: Android Only, iOS sound settings come in the push ,

mentioned [here](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/push/phonegap.html) .

Push Notifications are coming with sound, unable disable sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way by setting PushPreferences

```
PushPreferences prefs = PushManager.shared().getPreferences();
prefs.setSoundEnabled (false);
```